# how to pass select ID in js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting a solution to my main problem which is posted here [jQuery/js separating 2 drop down values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335744/jquery-js-separating-2-drop-down-values).
How would I go about passing `#dropdown1` in this bit here:

```
<select id="dropdown1" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

original

```
var lbl = ui.value;

if (ui.checked) {
    var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="'+lbl+'">';
    $("[id^=Main]:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>'+ctrl+lbl+'</div>');    
    });
}
```

I just dont know the syntax to go about it, would it be something like:

```
var lbl = ui.value;

if (ui.checked.'#dropdown1') {
    var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="'+lbl+'">';
    $("[id^=Main]:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>'+ctrl+lbl+'</div>');    
    });
}
```

As a side not, the original works fine. I'm trying to solve a problem in the link I posted above because I'm using 2 select widgets. see here:http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/60/

Comment: Use `$('#id_selector')` --> jQuery Object **or** `document.getElementById('id_selector')` --> DOM node, but I will set `flag` as low quality...

Comment: `if $('#dropdown1').checked {...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, change the condition like this:

```
if ($("#dropdown1").find("option:selected").text() != null) {
```

Fiddle is too slow over here. Try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function test() {
        if($("#dropdown1").find("option:selected").text() != null)
            alert('OK')
    }
</script>
<select id='dropdown1' onchange='test()'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The actual values in my project are being populated from an external js file which is why its pulling like it is to get the values. They are not actually declared in the html. The widget I'm using turns a multiselect dropdown into a dropdown of multiselect checkboxes.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'text' Are you able to get this working in my provided fiddle?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: NULL is not defined If you have it working, could you post the fiddle?

Comment: Change NULL to '' or null, null should be in lower case.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Unfortunately it didn't fix main problem as stated at the top in the other link haha.